# variable isnt using the specified id

Tags: php

I'm having a problem where i'm calling for my code to create a new file at the exact time someone registers using `fopen()` when it creates said new file its supposed to use the id of the newly registered user as the name of the file.

```
$script = fopen("00".$row["id"].".php", "w") or die("unable to open file!");
```

The problem i've run into is that its using the id 1 everytime. so the file is named 001 and as many times as you re register, it never makes more than 001.

Comment: Your question unfortunately doesn't make sense unless you add the rest of your code. Where does `$row['id']` come from? I suppose you are ready database records, but I can't see how...

Comment: So the actual issue is that `$row['id']` contains the value `1`. We cannot tell you why. That is why you need to find out.